# Mathematica code for hidden Markov models (HMM)

Tags: probability-or-statistics, stochastic-calculus

I am looking for some simple Mathematica code to model an HMM with just a few states and an equal number of observable signals (emissions). I am hoping to generate sample paths and keep track of the posterior probability of the system being in a given state. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is [this](http://nighttimecuriosities.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/hidden-markov-model-of-chicago-crimes.html) the sort of thing?

Comment: Here's a tutorial on fitting hidden markov models in Mathematica including an example applied to financial data. http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~frey/QuantitativeFinance/Resources/TutorialsWorkshops/

Comment: @Tox If you want to simulate paths [this](http://ze.phyr.us/simulating-markov-chains-in-mathematica) might be useful.

Comment: This needs a v10 answer :)

Answer (score 11):

*Mathematica* V10 introduced the following two functions:

### - [`HiddenMarkovProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HiddenMarkovProcess.html)

### - [`FindHiddenMarkovStates`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindHiddenMarkovStates.html)

---

Examples of their usage can be found [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-random-processes/find-hidden-states-underlying-given-emissions-of-h.html) and [here](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/enhanced-random-processes/estimate-hidden-markov-processes-from-data.html).

I've also used `HiddenMarkovProcess[]` here: [Detecting components in timeseries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104950/detecting-components-in-timeseries/104954#104954).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. I also found that there is a package with inbuilt functions, although super pricey, at http://scientificcomputing.blogspot.co.uk/2006/02/statistical-inference-package-for.html